# How to ensure overwriting doesn't happen while writing to text file from console in java?

Tags: java, console, overwrite

I am trying to write the console output to the text file (Data.txt) so here is my code:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("/home/cse/Desktop/Data.txt"));  
System.setOut(out);
out.print("");
```

When I run the program again after I have once run it, the output replaces the old data that was present in the Data.txt file. But I want it to continue adding the data from where it had stopped earlier. How can I do this?

Comment: You first point of call should **always** be the JavaDoc. Just looking at [the list of `PrintStream` constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#constructor.summary) tells you how to solve this problem. Also please *search* before posting.

Comment: Take a look on already asked questions: - [Append to text file using PrintStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805021/append-to-text-file-using-printstream) - [File Write - PrintStream append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043356/file-write-printstream-append)

Comment: Credit to [sphinks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1345788/sphinks), who found the original above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `FileOutputStream` created with [the constructor that accepts an `append` flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.lang.String-boolean-):

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/cse/Desktop/Data.txt", true));
```

The `true` states the new content will be appended to an existing file.

Answer (score -2):

Using out.append() should do the job for you.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("/home/cse/Desktop/Data.txt"));  
System.setOut(out);
out.append("");
```

Comment: It will still overwrite data.

Comment: Nope this doesn't work